# Cannot set WFS filter the second time

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Here is my scenario. The page loads and the map loads with an empty vector layer. So its there, but has no features. Then the user clicks a button and a CQL filter loads features according to the CQL settings.

My methodology to implement this. I set an empty vector layer, no `loader` or `strategy`. The button the user clicks for the first time calls a "initialization " function (=`firstTimeOnly()`) that:

- sets a `loader` and a `strategy` to the vector layer
- now that a `loader` exists, calls another "filtering" function (=`changeFilter()`) that
  resets the loader's cql filter and loads features
- now the "filtering" function gets attached to the button and called
  with every click. The "initialization" function served its purpose
  and detaches itself from the button.

Here is my code

```
<button id= "magicButton", onclick="firstTimeOnly()">Click me</button>

//set globals to use them
var cqlFilter = "name='testpoint9'";
var urlTemplate =  'http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:layerName&CQL_FILTER={{CQLFILTER}}&outputFormat=application/json';
var loader = function (extent) {
        var url = urlTemplate.replace('{{CQLFILTER}}', cqlFilter);
        $.ajax(url, {
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                var res = response;
                var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
            }
        })
    };

var strategy = new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}));

//empty vector source
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({});

function changeFilter() {
    //remove all, set cql and reload
    var featsToRemove = layerVector.getSource().getFeatures();
    for (var f=0;f<featsToRemove.length;f++)
    {
        layerVector.getSource().removeFeature(featsToRemove[f]);
    }
    cqlFilter = "name LIKE 'p'";
    sourceVector.clear(true);
}

layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceVector,
    style:styleFunction
});

function firstTimeOnly() {
    sourceVector.set('loader', loader);
    sourceVector.set('strategy', strategy);
    changeFilter();
    document.getElementById("magicButton").removeEventListener("click", firstTimeOnly, false);
    document.getElementById("magicButton").addEventListener("click", changeFilter, false);
}
```

This is based to [erilem's code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146791/how-to-update-url-parameters-cql-filter-in-openlayers-3) for cql filter resetting and if I use just his code works fine. But if I want to start with an empty layer and edit it as the above, I get nothing. My code gives no errors. But, if I click the button I get nothing.

Please advide me how to fix this. Or maybe its an overkill and you suggest something smarter.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I put

`console.log("loader  "+sourceVector.get('loader'));`

at the end of the changeFilter I get the loader function. So, I guess the first time I click the button, the firstTimeOnly actually sets a loader and calls changeFilter. So, the loader is there, but does not work? Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into potential issues with Openlayers the issue I see is that `removeEventListener` only works for removing listeners that were set with `addEventListener`. Since you bound the `onclick` declaratively in the HTML the way to unbind it would be by doing `document.getElementById("magicButton").onclick = null`.

That said I would change your example so that somewhere in your code you set the event listener using `addEventListener`.

Example:

```
function firstTimeOnly() {
    sourceVector.set('loader', loader);
    sourceVector.set('strategy', strategy);
    changeFilter();
    document.getElementById("magicButton").removeEventListener("click", firstTimeOnly, false);
    document.getElementById("magicButton").addEventListener("click", changeFilter, false);
}
document.getElementById("magicButton").addEventListener("click", firstTimeOnly, false);
```

And get rid of the `onclick` in the HTML.

Also consider caching the reference to `magicButton` so that you don't have to be constantly calling `getElementById`.

`var magicButton = document.getElementById("magicButton");`

Comment: Yes, you are right , has to do with adding/removing listeners in Javascript and not Openlayers. Sorry, I had to go for  a couple of days and didnt have access to a pc, so I could not give you the bounty points. The first answer suppose to take the points automatically. Did you got them?

Comment: I did not, probably because I didn't have any votes by the time it expired. No worries though.